# Indexing in python Issue

Tags: python, indexing, logical-operators

I am wondering how to access the values in one array that correspond to the values in another array.

For example, I have two arrays that are related by a non-linear equation. I only want to look at the values between greater than 0 and less than 15. I index in the following way:

```
data['SNR'] = np.array(data['SNR'])
snr = data['SNR']
domain = np.array(domain) 
domain = domain[snr>0] 
domain = domain[snr<15]
snr = snr[snr>0]
snr = snr[snr<15]
```

but I get the error that there are too many boolean indices in the last call. I do not know how to remedy this.

Comment: FYI: `snr>0` and `snr<15` will return `True` or `False`. And those will taken as keyword. and in `snr[snr>0]` here the True or False return will be treated as variable. Please give more information on your code. I have put my understanding. Please correct if I'am wrong.

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan That's not true, as `snr` is a numpy array. Conditional statements on numpy arrays are applied element-wise. So `snr < 0` will return a boolean array marking which elements it is true for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
domain = domain[snr>0] 
domain = domain[snr<15]
```

To use boolean indexing in numpy, the arrays need to be the same length. I'm assuming that `domain` and `snr` are the same length originally, but after you perform `domain = domain[snr>0]`, which removes some elements, it is shorter than `snr`, so you get an error.

The solution is to use numpy's [logical operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations) to combine the boolean arrays you get from each condition into a single one. In this case:

```
cond = np.logical_and(snr > 0, snr < 15)
domain = domain[cond] 
snr = snr[cond]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
snr[array(map(bool, 1*(snr>0)*(snr<15))) ]
```

Something more readable is list comprehension, which I would recommenr ...

```
aray([ s for s in snr if s>0 and s < 15])
```